# Getting ToolStripItem that initiated ContextMenuStrip by keyboard

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In WinForms, only ToolStrip can have ContextMenuStrip, not ToolStripItem.

As I need ContextMenuStrip to know which button user refers to, I have a solution when button is pressed by mouse (by getting cursor position at ContextMenuStrip.Openning, and then getting item from ToolStrip), but I have no solution for keyboard selection. In theory, one could try to capture OnKeyDown of ToolStrip and try to track which item is selected by user action, but in practice if ToolStrip is overflowed it might get pretty complicated and probably unreliable.

Is there any solution for this?

SOLUTION:

I played a little, and here is the solution, in ContextMenuStrip.Opening handler do this:
`toolStrip.Items.Cast<ToolStripItem>().Where(x => x.Selected).First()` to get item that was selected when key was pressed to show ContextMenuStrip.

Comment: Erm, what key do you expect your user to press?  There's no way to focus toolstrip items with the keyboard.  Nobody is going to select an item with the mouse and then press a key.

Comment: If ToolStrip has focus, you can use arrow keys (and depending on Properties also Tab key) and it will change selected ToolStripItem. You can even press Enter, and it will activate Click event. And if you press key for ContextMenu, it will activate ContextMenu. That is not a problem. The problem is which ToolStripItem was selected before

Comment: Hmm, I don't repro that at all, can't give the ToolStrip the focus.  Posting a small repro project that behaves this way on a file sharing service would be wise if you want an answer.

Comment: I've solved the problem and posted above, I don't have idea why it didn't work for you, did you have ToolStripItems on ToolStrip? You have used ToolStrip.Focus() method?

Comment: Yes, buttons.  Post an answer instead and accept it so it gets preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played a little, and here is the solution, in ContextMenuStrip.Opening handler do this: `toolStrip.Items.Cast<ToolStripItem>().Where(x => x.Selected).First()` to get item that was selected when key was pressed to show ContextMenuStrip.